# How to speed up a C# program to run quickly in the first run?

Tags: c#, winforms, caching

I have a program that takes folder as input and processes images in it.

When I run the program for the first time, around 5 images are processed in one second.

In the second run, it processes 20 images in one second.

In subsequent runs, it processes around 50 images in one second.

I understand that this has definitely something to do with cache.

My question is, what should I do to run the program quickly in the first iteration?

This is very much important to me because my clients need to run the program only once a day and hence it needs to be speedy in the first run.

Update 1: This is a windows based application.

Thanks.

Comment: *I understand that this has definitely something to do with cache.* What cache you're talking about? also what program? console app? winforms? wpf? or what?

Comment: This is probably because the images are cached by the disk. Get a faster disk would be the first priority.

Comment: @SriramSakthivel, its a windows program.

Comment: Then you want to simply speed up the program. Try using a profiler to see which parts of the code take the most time.

Comment: I assume you are using threading loading the images? Use can also look at this library that loads images faster using GDI Plus: http://weblogs.asp.net/justin_rogers/pages/131704.aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bottleneck here is a speed of accessing data on the disk.

Depending on what kind of image processing you do, you may speed it up (by using better/faster libraries or optimizations), that would makes number of image processed in each consecutive run bigger.

If you had (images/sec)

> 20, 30, 50, 50, 50

then it will become

> 21, 32, 53, 53, 53

or

> 30, 45, 75, 75, 75

depending on how long processing takes compared to loading. You can use profiler or simple measure loading/processing time to get better understanding what you may win at max (which is reducing processing time to zero in theory).

---

If you are trying to make

> 50, 50, 50, 50, 50

then its impossible via software, because you need time to load images and this time has to be spend. You may try to use cache to pre-cache something, yet you will win nothing, because **total execution** time of your program still be same on the first run and if run it second time (when caching already occurs), it will still be in average (total execution time / total images)

> 20, 30, 50, 50, 50

Even if you use SSD, there still be a lower speed during first run, because memory (Windows disk cache) is faster. Still taking faster disk (SSD RAID? =D) will increase speed of loading by significant amount (assuming you have normal HDD now), yet, processing time still be the same.

---

Why do you want to have your program to run faster? Perhaps because it has to be run manually or otherwise blocking user from using Windows or some other your software? Then how about making this processing in background with **very low speed** to do not disturb the user? It can starts together with Windows and use some IPC with that other software (or even be a part of it) to determine when/what/how to process. As a good example, take very good antivirus with alot of heuristic (which means long processing time), you will not want to run it every day to scan everything (it takes a lot of time and it's quite intensive), but if it runs in background, doing only *necessary* job with weekly/monthly scans at scheduled time (when PC is used less), then it's absolutely no problem.